# ASCII to EBCDIC conversion including (decimal packed comp-3 conversion) for a float value using python 2.7

Tags: python, scripting, ebcdic

I need help with converting my file from ASCII to EBCDIC before sending it to the vendor. Has anyone implemented this kind of solution using python 2.7 in their projects?

My File row data looks like the below:

```
 -----------------------------------
 12345ABC6789 000006.12DEF
 -----------------------------------
```

It is a fixed fixed-width file, and I can break it like this.

```
------------------------------------
 Field   Data          Length
 ------------------------------------------
 Field1 '12345'        05
 Field2 'ABC'          03
 Field3 '6789'         04
 Field4 ' 000006.12'   10
 Field5 'DEF'          03
 ------------------------------------
```

My Target EBCDIC layout from vendor looks like this.

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
 Level & Cobol Name   Picture Clause       Start   End
 ------------------------------------------------------
 Field1               X(05)                 1       5
 Field2               X(03)                 6       8
 Field3               X(04)                 9       12
 Field4               S9(06)V99 COMP-3      13      17
 Field5               X(03)                 18      20
 ------------------------------------------------------
```

Entire row should be converted to EBCDIC format and while doing that need to make sure field4 is converted.

Thanks in advance.

I tried a couple of things in python but not getting the expected results.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your Q, it's really unclear what problems you're facing. Preferably, provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem. Also, check the formatting of your posting.

Comment: your forgot to include your current code you need help with

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An option (if you can run Java programs) is to write a Csv file and use https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/ (written in java) to Convert the Csv file to Cobol (it can do the ebcdic conversion as well).